# How to exit a git commit in a hook with eslint?

Tags: eslint, githooks

I try to find a solution to exit my code when the linter is linting a warning line or error line using ESLINT.

**My code in my package.json :**

```
"eslint": "npx eslint ./checkOnly.js --fix --exit-on-fatal-error --max-warnings 1",
```

**Hook "commit-msg" :**

```
#!/bin/sh
cd src/main/webapp
npm run eslint
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Linting"
    echo "============================================================"
    exit 1
fi
```

When I try to execute the command `npm run eslint`, the linter clean my code and everything is ok. But when I'm using the command `git commit -a -m "testcommit"`, the linter find a line to clean, clean the line but don't exit the commit...

Comment: I would assume that eslint does not error, when it can fix the linting error. If you remove the `--fix` flag from the command, it should work as expected.

Comment: Oh I also just saw this in the [documentation](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/user-guide/command-line-interface#exit-codes): You can try to add `--max-warnings 0` to your eslint command line. Maybe this works?